# How to pivot base one column with related column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I want to select some rows in column base on one column.

I have this data:

```
PersonID  PersonDep  PersonBranch  RoleName  RoleDep  RoleBranch  IsPriority  RoleLevel
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         x1         y1            Manager   x2       y2          1           Role1
1         x1         y1            User      x3       y3          0           Role2
2         x4         y4            Admin     x2       y2          0           Role1
2         x4         y4            User      x6       y6          0           Role2
2         x4         y4            Manager   x7       y7          0           Role3
3         b1         d1            NULL      NULL     NULL        NULL         NULL
```

i want this Result:

```
PersonID PersonDep PersonBranch Role1 RoleName         RoleDep RoleBranch Role2 RoleName RoleDep RoleBranch Role3 RoleName RoleDep RoleBranch
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        x1        y1           Role1 Manager(priorit) x2      y2         Role2 User     x3      y3         NULL  NULL     NULL    NULL
2        x4        y4           Role1 Admin            x2      y2         Role2 User     x6      y6         Role3 Manager  x7      y7
3        b1        d1           NULL  NULL             NULL    NULL       NULL  NULL     NULL    NULL       NULL  NULL     NULL    NULL
```

any body can solve this problem with unkown `RoleLevel` Count?

Comment: what is the rule / conditions ? can you explain how to get from your data to the result ?

Comment: each `PersonID` can have some Role . i want to show one row for each `PersonID` with Roles.'

Comment: the expecting result seemed to be like unnormalized

Comment: @alfin-e-r no - its totally normalized

Answer (score 4):

use `CASE .. WHEN` with aggregate function

```
; with 
cte as
(
   select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by PersonID order by RoleName)
   from   yourtable
)
select PersonID, PersonDep  PersonBranch,
       RoleName1   = max(case when rn = 1 then RoleName end),
       RoleDep1    = max(case when rn = 1 then RoleDep end),
       RoleBranch1 = max(case when rn = 1 then RoleBranch end),
       RoleName2   = max(case when rn = 2 then RoleName end),
       . . .
from   cte
group by PersonID, PersonDep  PersonBranch
```

Comment: if Role are dynamic - how write this code?

Comment: you mean you have unknown no of roles per person ? In that case you will need to use `Dynamic SQL`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you use dynamic SQL, there is no way to pivoting on unknown number of columns.

With dynamic SQL you need to loop trough your rows and build an SQL command with all columns.

if you can specify a high bound for `RoleLevel` you can use standard `PIVOT` with some trick to pivot more than one column

Comment: ok - can you write this code?

Comment: if you look on google or here on stackoverflow you will found dozens of examples